# Using array_rand() in PHP and I'm getting an out of range error

Tags: php, arrays, class, methods

I'm a total new to PHP and I'm having a logic problem in my code (array_rand($arrCards,1) is running out of elements before it should, I think).  So I've done a var_dump of the array and I get this output (brief excerpt):

```
    array (size=52)
  0 => 
    object(Card)[2]
      private 'suit' => string 'heart' (length=5)
      private 'rank' => string 'a' (length=1)
  1 => 
    object(Card)[3]
      private 'suit' => string 'heart' (length=5)
      private 'rank' => string '2' (length=1)
  2 => 
    object(Card)[4]
      private 'suit' => string 'heart' (length=5)
      private 'rank' => string '3' (length=1)
```

**Here's my Card class:**

```
class Card {
    //properties
    private $suit;
    private $rank;

    //constructor
    public function __construct($r, $s) {
        $this->rank = $r;
        $this->suit = $s;
    }

    //methods
    public function getSuit() {
        return $this->suit;
    }

    public function getRank() {
        return $this->rank;
    }

}
```

**And here is how I create each card and push it into each array (this is the Deck class constructor):**

```
//constructor
    public function __construct() {
        $this->arrCards = array();

        $objCard = new Card("a", "heart");
        array_push($this->arrCards, $objCard);
        $objCard = new Card("2", "heart");
        array_push($this->arrCards, $objCard);
        $objCard = new Card("3", "heart");
blah blah continued...
```

(It's been pointed out to me that I could have constructed the Deck using two for loops, but I've typed it all out now so that probably doesn't matter.)

**Here's the relevant methods in the Deck class:**

```
//methods
    public function dealCard() {
        if ($this->hasCard()) {
            echo $this->intCount . PHP_EOL;
            $index = array_rand($this->arrCards, 1);
            $card = array_splice($this->arrCards,$index);
            return $card[0];
        } else {
            return Null;
        }
    }

    protected function hasCard() {
        if ($this->intCount > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Here's the error I get (preceded by the `echo $this->intCount;` (note how it's not actually removing the card from the deck like I intend it to either):

```
52 52 52 52 
( ! ) Warning: array_rand(): Second argument has to be between 1 and the number of elements in the array in C:\wamp64\www\ofc\ofc_classes.php on line 162
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  240704  {main}( )   ...\main.php:0
2   0.0010  348080  Deck->dealCard( )   ...\main.php:11
3   0.0010  348176  array_rand ( )  ...\ofc_classes.php:162
```

Comment: Can you, in a couple of words, explain what is the premise? are you dealing a fixed number of cards from a 52 card deck .. do you shuffle the deck before each draw .. it would help a lot :)

Comment: @Alex Andrei No, I don't need to shuffle it as that's equivalent to what array_rand() is doing (just one shuffle at a time).  I'm dealing a set number of cards from a standard deck.  I originally shuffled it using shuffle() and then popped a card off, but I thought (without any reason other than a "just in case") that having the shuffled deck available in memory (albeit on the server) leaves open the possibility that a hacker can get access to the order of the cards before they are dealt.

Comment: so, in brief, from a 52 card deck, shuffled 1 time, you want to deal X cards, removing them from the deck, correct?

Comment: Essentially.  Except they aren't shuffled one time.  They are essentially shuffled each time a card is drawn via the array_rand() function.

Comment: the issue is with your use of `array_rand` and `array_splice`. you are not removing the actual dealt card. I will explain in an answer shortly

Comment: Your `hasCard` method would probably be better using `if(count($this->arrCards) > 0 )` as it saves having an array and another variable with a count of values in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`array_rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) will return a random key from your input array, while
[`array_splice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) with the offset positive, will remove that many elements from the array starting from the beginning of the array.

Example:

```
$deck = ['A','K','Q','J','10','9','8','7','6','5','4','3','2','1'];
$card = array_rand($deck,1);

print $card . PHP_EOL;
// let's assume it outputs 9, this is the key from the array
// array_rand returns a random key from the input array

$remainingDeck = array_splice($deck,$card);
print_r($remainingDeck) . PHP_EOL;
// will output
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 1
)
```

Which is not what you expect, we have eliminated 9 cards from the deck, instead of just one.

The warning you get is telling you that, after a couple of dealt cards, your deck is empty.
You can easily verify this by printing out the `count` of the `$this->arrCards` after dealing each card instead of relying on `$this->intCount` which does not get updated after dealing the cards.

Comment: Cheers for that @Alex Andrei.  Silly mistakes.  Forgot to add 1 as the third parameter of the splice() function.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably change the `dealCard()` and `hasCard()` methods:

```
public function dealCard()
{
    $result = null;
    if ($this->hasCard()) {
        $index = array_rand($this->arrCards, 1);
        $card = array_splice($this->arrCards, $index, 1);
        $result = $card[0];
    }
    return $result;
}

public function hasCard()
{
    $result = (!empty($this->arrCard));
    return $result;
}
```

what and why:

- I like using `$result` for a method/function - you always know `$result` is what you are expecting to be returned
- initialise the `$result` - if the code doesn't behave as you expect it to
  you'll always get something returned
- use [array_splice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) function with the length parameter - you only need 1 card from the deck
- 1 exit point to the method - this is a simple method, but more complicated ones with multiple exit (`return`) points can be difficult to debug later
- use [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function to check if there are more cards - it saves using/maintaining a counter of cards in the deck

Comment: Cheers for that.  Good ideas.

Comment: @erv and don't forget to use [srand()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.srand.php) or you'll end up getting the same 'random' cards dealt

Comment: it doesn't need srand().  array_rand() reseeds itself.